# CRM 2011 Rest Builder solution gives 500 Internal Error when executing or calling

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamics-crm, odata, dynamics-crm-2011

I have installed `CRM Rest Builder` on my `CRM 2011 SDK`(on premise ) , And it works good.
But Now it behaves some strange. 
I have entity named `new_device`.
It has `N:1` relation with `salesorder` (order) ; `new_device` ans secondary entity and `salesorder` as primary entity.
I create an OData Request, which  return `new_device` s which salesorder's status code of them is complete.
The rest builder give me this with below URL:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    datatype: "json",
    url: Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() +
 "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/new_deviceSet?$select=new_ProductPrimaryCategoryId,new_RelatedOrderId&$expand=new_salesorder_new_device&$filter=new_salesorder_new_device/StatusCode/Value eq 100001",
    beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    },
    async: true,
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        var results = data.d.results;
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var new_ProductPrimaryCategoryId = results[i].new_ProductPrimaryCategoryId;
            var new_RelatedOrderId = results[i].new_RelatedOrderId;
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

It gives me the `500 internal server error` even when I execute it in Rest Builder by clicking Execute Code.
But when I change the filter from equals to contain it works good ! 
It means when I try to retrieve new_devices that their salesorder status code contains data, like below :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    datatype: "json",
    url: Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/new_deviceSet?$select=new_ProductPrimaryCategoryId,new_RelatedOrderId&$expand=new_salesorder_new_device&$filter=new_salesorder_new_device/ StatusCode ne null",
    beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    },
    async: true,
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        var results = data.d.results;
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var new_ProductPrimaryCategoryId = results[i].new_ProductPrimaryCategoryId;
            var new_RelatedOrderId = results[i].new_RelatedOrderId;
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

What is the problem?

Edit : When I try to call via SDK.REST or SDK.JQUERY or XrmSvsToolkit it gives me :

```
Error : 500: Internal Server Error: attributeName
```

Comment: You can test this in your code or browser console to see the behavior & isolate any issue. Xrmtoolbox Fetchxml Builder too..

Comment: What happens when you put the url directly to browser ?

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar : It returns the same result.
500 Internal Error.